# Timepicker the field must be a date - validation fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

My code is similar to this one: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax

The DateTime partial view:

```
@model DateTime?
@( Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m) )
```

and the binding in the grid:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Timestamp).Width(110);
```

And the field in my model class:

```
public DateTime Timestamp
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

However, when I enter value bigger that 12 for a day, I get error the field must be a date. This is so annoying! How to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
After much head scratching and trial and error this is what worked for me.

Time partial view

```
@model DateTime?

@(Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m => m)
.Min(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0)) //Set min time of the timepicker
      .Max(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0)) //Set min date of the timepicker
      .Value(DateTime.Now) //Set the value of the timepicker
)
```

The ViewModel

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please select a start time")]
[Display(Name = "Start time")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[UIHint("Time")]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
```

The View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.StartTime)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.StartTime)
```

Unobtrusive validation now seems to work and the error message "Start Time must be a date" doesn't seem to appear. It still fails validation if the timepicker box is left unfilled.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Data annotations can provide the DatePickerFor the correct data type to use.  Add the following data annotation to the Class Property declaration:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
```

Razor View:

```
@model DateTime?
@( Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m) )
```

Binding:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Timestamp).Width(110);
```

Class:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime Timestamp
{
    get; set;
}
```